# FCKEditor toolbar configuration in PHP

Tags: php, fckeditor

I am working on an application where I'm using FCKEditor but I need to modify the toolbar options. I searched for this and got the answer that I need to change the array defined in toolbar JS file. But I didn't find that toolbar plugin in my plugins directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with PHP
Take a look at the fckconfig.js file to see these two sample toolbarsets definitions:

```
FCKConfig.ToolbarSets["Default"] = [
['Source','DocProps','-','Save','NewPage','Preview','-','Templates'],
['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteWord','-','Print','SpellCheck'],
['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],
['Form','Checkbox','Radio','TextField','Textarea','Select','Button','ImageButton','HiddenField'],
'/',
['Bold','Italic','Underline','StrikeThrough','-','Subscript','Superscript'],
['OrderedList','UnorderedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyFull'],
['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],
['Image','Flash','Table','Rule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak'],
'/',
['Style','FontFormat','FontName','FontSize'],
['TextColor','BGColor'],
['FitWindow','ShowBlocks','-','About'] // No comma for the last row.
] ;

FCKConfig.ToolbarSets["Basic"] = [
['Bold','Italic','-','OrderedList','UnorderedList','-','Link','Unlink','-','About']
] ;
```

**Edit**
read this: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar

Comment: Plz tell me where i find this fckconfig.js file. Coz i just find a file with name config.js at root of CKEditor

Comment: so read this:http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.toolbar (If my answer will help you, click on the V on the left of my answer)

Comment: I got that file, it was in ckeditor/_source/plugins/toolbar. But when i m changing the items in name it did not take effect.

Comment: each time you change it, you need to clear cache i think. you may also try CTRL + F5. also note that you might not changing the correct toolbar

Comment: Thanks for your help fatnjazzy.But i shorted out this problem by editing in ckeditor.js where i found "i.toolbar_Full".But i din'nt understand that . Is this js file combining the other js? Looking for your great help. Thanks in advance.